# How to export data from bigquery to apps scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

How to export large data from bigquery to apps scripts?
I ve tried method **BigQuery.TableData.list()** but with large data it just doesnt work.
Also i ve tried to do it with simple Query

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

But it returns only 70000 of 1.2M.
How to export this data in json file with job?Or what is other solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use **BigQuery.Jobs.query()** function to get your data and export it to JSON.

However, this function only retrieves ALL rows from one page of the query result.

For you to retrieve all other data from all pages of the query result, you will need to add the below `while` loop using **pageToken** for `jobs.getQueryResults()` parameter to loop and concatenate the retrieve rows per page as shown on below code. The `jobs.getQueryResults()` can only return up to 20MB that is why we will be needing to loop and concatenate through pages. You may refer to this [Paging Through Tables Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/paging-results#paging) for more details.

```
function myFunction() {
  var projectId = '<project_ID>';

  var request = {
    query: 'SELECT * ' +
      'FROM `publicdata.samples.shakespeare`;',
    useLegacySql: false
  };

  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;
  queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);

  var rows = queryResults.rows;
 
  while (queryResults.pageToken) {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
      pageToken: queryResults.pageToken
    });
    rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);
  }
  
  console.log(rows.length);
}
```

Below is the execution result of the code without using the `while` loop. I was able to retrieve only 87500 out of 164656 total rows from the *shakespeare* table.
[image]

Below is the execution result of the code that is using the `while` loop. I was able to retrieve all 164656 out of 164656 total rows from the *shakespeare* table.
[image]

**UPDATE:**
Please see below updated code:

```
 function myFunction() {
      var projectId = '<project_ID>';
    
      var request = {
        query: 'SELECT * ' +
          'FROM `bigquery-public-data.census_bureau_usa.population_by_zip_2010`;',
        useLegacySql: false
      };
    
      var max = 10000;
    
      var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId, {
          maxResults: max
        });
    
      var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;
      queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
          maxResults: max
        });
    
      var rows = queryResults.rows;
    
     let i = 0;
     while (i < 5) {
        queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
          pageToken: queryResults.pageToken,
          maxResults: max
        });
         i++;
        rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows); 
      }
      
      console.log(rows.length);
    }
```

I used the *bigquery-public-data.census_bureau_usa.population_by_zip_2010* since it has 1.6M records to replicate the big data similar to your scenario. I also added an iteration in order to confirm that we are able to retrieve specific number of rows from a big dataset.

See below result of successful execution that was able to retrieve 60000 rows out of 1.6M records based on our loop condition.

[image]

However, when we remove the iteration and use the `while (queryResults.pageToken)` as done on my first answer, we will be encountering `out of memory` or `runtime exit` (when we use *BigQuery.TableData.list()* method) since it will get all rows from a big dataset in which App Script might not handle due to certain limits. You may see this [App Script Quota Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) for your reference.

I suggest to use a Virtual Machine where you can host your code and be able to handle big data retrieval.

Comment: After queryResult = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectID,jobId);
i have an error.
The JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly.
Same error i have when i tried to get rows by TableData.List()

Comment: Hi @Kirill Az, I have updated my posted answer. You may refer to it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks you a lot!