# Google BigQuery pagination does not return value I specified

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I have a bigQuery query I am executing via Java client. I am asking for 50k batches, but after first iteration, big query returns random number of batches. Does anyone knows why is that?

```
 var queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query)
                .setWriteDisposition(JobInfo.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
                .setDestinationTable(tableId)
                .setAllowLargeResults(true)
                .build();

        JobId jobId = JobId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        Job queryJob = bigquery.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).setJobId(jobId).build());
        TableResult results = queryJob.getQueryResults(BigQuery.QueryResultsOption.pageSize(50000));

        //First Page
        results
                .getValues()
                .forEach(row -> {
                    //System.out.println(row);
                    //some job
                });


        long i = 0;
        long count = 0;

        while (results.hasNextPage()) {
            logger.info("Paginated result size: {} in page {}", results.getTotalRows(), results.getNextPageToken());
            results = results.getNextPage();
            count += results.getValues().spliterator().getExactSizeIfKnown();
            results
                    .getValues()
                    .forEach(row -> {
                        //System.out.println(row);
                        //some job
              });
            logger.info("iteration {}. Progress: {} / {}", i, count, results.getTotalRows());
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Logs:

```
iteration 0. Progress: 38720 / 158226305
iteration 1. Progress: 69091 / 158226305
iteration 2. Progress: 88977 / 158226305
iteration 3. Progress: 114797 / 158226305
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `jobs.getQueryResult`, from the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/paging-results#paging) :

> jobs.getQueryResult can return 20 MB of data unless explicitly requested more through support.

Looking at your total number of rows (158m), I am assuming each page has more than **20MB** data therefore it shows only rows up to that size. You may try to reduce the page size(maybe around 30K) and check.

An Example :

```
String query ="select commit, author, repo_name from `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits` "
                     +"where subject like '%bigquery%' or subject like '%github%' ";

QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query)
        .setWriteDisposition(JobInfo.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
        .setDestinationTable(tableId)
        .build();

JobId jobId = JobId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
Job queryJob = bigquery.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).setJobId(jobId).build());

TableResult results = queryJob.getQueryResults(BigQuery.QueryResultsOption.pageSize(PAGE_SIZE));
//returns 4.5m records
//rest of the code is same
```

Page size = 50K

```
iteration 0. Progress: 35693 / 4535455===========> 35693 //no of rows for this iteration
iteration 1. Progress: 70713 / 4535455===========> 35020
iteration 2. Progress: 102060 / 4535455===========> 31347
iteration 3. Progress: 128034 / 4535455===========> 25974
...
```

Page Size = 20K

```
iteration 0. Progress: 20000 / 4535455===========> 20000
iteration 1. Progress: 40000 / 4535455===========> 20000
iteration 2. Progress: 60000 / 4535455===========> 20000
iteration 3. Progress: 80000 / 4535455===========> 20000
iteration 4. Progress: 100000 / 4535455===========> 20000
...
```

Also as you are using `allowLargeResults` with a specific destination I think  you should go through this [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#large-results) regarding the same if not done already.

**N.B** If your goal is to process as much data as possible in a single iteration you may follow this [similar StackoverFlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71085813/how-to-export-data-from-bigquery-to-apps-scripts).

Comment: Thanks, I think I have missed 20 MB limit on documentation. I reduced limit and it works as I expected. I also read your edit, do you think there is something which is not correct on my code?

Comment: Nothing much only that you are using `.setAllowLargeResults(true)` and as per documention it can be used only in **`legecy SQL`** (setUseLegacySql(true)) also as per doc *You cannot specify a top-level ORDER BY, TOP or LIMIT clause* . Just check the documentation whether you are doing it correctly or not.